# React 16.3+ correct way to fire onChange from state change

Tags: javascript, reactjs

So I have this component:

```
import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { isEqual } from 'lodash';

class SomeComponent extends React.Component {
  static propTypes = {
    onChange: PropTypes.func,
  };

  previousItems = [];

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      items: ['some', 'list'],
    };
  }

  setState(stateSetter) {
    super.setState(previousState => {
      const newState = stateSetter(previousState);

      if (!isEqual(newState.items, this.previousItems)) {
        this.props.onChange && this.props.onChange(newState.items);
        this.previousItems = newState.items;
      }

      return newState;
    });
  }
}
```

And what I'm trying to do is listen to change to state and fire `onChange` when that state changes. I used to do this using `componentWillUpdate` but I hear that will change in React 17.

What's the correct way to do it now? What I did above feels hacky.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

[Check the docs for componentDidUpdate()](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidupdate)

This is where side effects should happen, as ajax calls or in this case, calling the onChange, but you must check if the props really changed (as you do in your code).

Note that this method is not called in the initial render, only on the next updates. Perfect for the onChange event.

Note that if the onChange method sets the state, it can start an infinite loop (fire onChange -> set state -> fire onChange -> ....). If necessary, check what state/prop changed and fire the onChange event only when necessary (avoiding the infinite loop).

Comment: Setting state in `componentDidUpdate` can result in infinite loops.

Comment: but the OP said that he needs to call a `onChange` method. It seems reasonable that if on the `onChange`, I change the props/state, it will fire onChange again (and potentially begin an infinite loop). Changing the answer to include a note about infinite loop

Answer (score 1):

To clear things up, here is short description of upcoming React update path. Deprecation warnings will roll out on next minor React update so as early as in 16.4 but deprecated methods will work until next major version 17 update.

I would not recommend doing `setState` in `componentDidUpdate` life-cycle method since it makes you very vulnerable to infite loops.

I'm not quite sure what is that you try to achieve by checking if your `state` has changed and state change should always be cause by user action. Your component will automatically re-render when you call setState tho.

To clear things up, I would myself do something like this. You do state changes based on user actions and your React-components will always re-render when you call setState. This is by Reacts nature.

If I would like to pass data I would declare child component and pass data as props. Then pass it to child components state example with newly introduced in React 16.3 `getDerivedStateFromProps` -method which returns plain object and that gets automatically passed to components state. This method is called on initial render and as well every time that components receives new props, so basically every time when your parent component state changes, in this ocasion.

You can also `return null` from `getDerivedStateFromProps` -method if you don't want child-component to re-render.

```
class MyComponent extends React.Component {
  // ES7 syntax, same as doing this in constructor
  // with, this.state = {}
  state = {
    value: false
  }

  handleClick = () => {
    /* Might as well write some logic here
     * and do setState at end
     */
    const { value } = this.state        

    /* and at end, well I just return value negated back */
    this.setState({
      value: !value
    })
  }

  render() {
    const { value } = this.state
    return (
      <div>
        {value ? 'im true' : 'im falsy'}
        <button onClick={this.handleClick} >Click me!</button>
        <SomeOtherComponent {...this.state} />
      </div>
    )
  }

}



class SomeOtherComponent extends React.Component {
  static getDerivedStateFromProps(nextProps, prevState) {
    if (nextProps.value) {
      return { text: 'it was true ' }
    }
    return { text: 'it was falsy' }
  }

  state = {
    text: null,
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        { this.state.text }
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```